# Crysis Crashes on Startup With R9 290

Tags: technical-issues, crysis

Whenever I start Crysis on my new custom built desktop, it starts in a full black screen and nothing happens. I have to CTRL + ALT + Delete to get back to the desktop and only to find a window that says 'Crysis has stopped working'. My new rig has the following specs:

- AMD FX-8320 3.5GHz 8 Core CPU
- MSI R9 290 4GB GDDR5 Gaming GPU
- 8 GB DDR3 RAM
- 650 w PSU
- Windows 7 Home Premium x64
- Latest Catalyst Control Center

Comment: Standard set of have you updated all your drivers and is it a legal copy of the game question goes here.

Comment: @Sorean Yes, I updated my AMD drivers and bought it from Origin.

Comment: Check the application folder in the event log for the error prior to crashing. I might give you some direction there.